# DELTA DIAView SCADA how to define public variables?

Tags: delta, scada

About DELTA DIAView SCADA

I defined a variable in Timescript

I want access this variable from within a window

For example display this variable in a label

However it gives error

Please advice

[image: here the screenshot of error]

I tried public key in front of variable name but it didnot help

Comment: Doesn't appear to be [tag:vbscript], please included only relevant tags. Can you explain what "Timescript" is in SCADA?

Comment: timescript is VBscript code in DIAView SCADA SW which is for example called at start of program like initialize macro in HMIs

Comment: Do you have a reference for that, I've tried to find something on timescript?

Comment: DELTA has a manual for DIAView in its web page  https://downloadcenter.deltaww.com/en-US/DownloadCenter?v=1&CID=06&itemID=060701&sort_expr=cdate&sort_dir=DESC